# XSLT How do I use an XML ID to call an image with the same value?

Tags: xslt

I am trying to get data from an XML file that does NOT have a url to the linked photos.

However, the photos have the listing ID in their name so I am trying to do something like this;

```
<xsl:value-of select="concat('<img src="images/Photo','Listing/ListingID','-1.jpeg" width="100%">')"/>
```

to get pull my listing.

It will not let me have the < in the sting so I get  the following error:

```
error on line 34 at column 56: Unescaped '<' not allowed in attributes values.
```

I assume the problem comes from the quotes in the img element. I then have three different sets of quotes and only two types of quotation marks.

Can someone help me find the best way of showing these images?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Escape the characters `<` typing `&lt;` and `&gt;` for `>`.

---

**Edit**

As per your comment, I believe it is caused by unproper termination of a single quote :

```
<img src="images/Photo','Listing/ListingID','-1.jpeg" width="100%">
                                                   ^
```

Change the line for

```
<img src="images/Photo','Listing/ListingID','-1.jpeg'" width="100%">
```

Comment: Thanks. That seemed to fix that error but now giving me:
error on line 34 at column 69: attributes construct error

Comment: @LeeGellie I have no idea what is your line 34.

Comment: It is the line I posted in the original question.

Comment: Yes indeed. Sorry, as I am a "newbe" to StackOverflow they wouldn't let me give answers until more rep.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of trying to solve this as a problem in string manipulation, you should take the high way and treat it as a problem in transforming XML (something which XSLT is good at):

```
<img src="images/Photo{Listing/ListingID}-1.jpeg" width="100%"/>
```

This is assuming you want to insert a value from your input XML (`Listing/ListingID`) in between the two strings `"images/Photo"` and `"-1.jpeg"`. This is not entirely clear from your original code, since you have quoted all three components.

Comment: Looking at your profile, I have to say you are really patient to answer only `xslt` questions. Seems like most of the xslt questions are asked by students who have to use it in a project, they drop their code here and never give any feedback.